# jquery waypoints on specific animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-waypoints

I'm using waypoint with [jquery-circle-progress](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) The problem is that the circle appears only when the offset is reach. Is there a way to show the circle and do the animation when the offset is reach ?

[jQuery Circle Progress (animation start event)](https://jsfiddle.net/fvfnuqdu/6/)

```js
var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('circle2'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    
     $('#circle2').circleProgress();
     this.destroy()
  },
                      
                      offset: '50%'
                
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.0/circle-progress.min.js"></script>

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
<div id="circle2" data-value="0.75" data-empty-fill="grey" data-fill='{"color":"blue"}' data-thickness="15"></div>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure. The trick is:

1. Initially override the circle value with `0`:

   ```
   var el = $('#circle').circleProgress({value: 0});
   ```

   This will draw an "empty" circle (no animation will happen if the circle value is `0`).
2. Then create a `Waypoint`:

   ```
   new Waypoint({
     element: el.get(0),
     handler: function() {
       el.circleProgress({
         value: el.data('value')
       });
       this.destroy();
     },
     offset: '50%'
   });
   ```

Here's [a working demo](http://jsbin.com/qupohek/3/edit?js,output), and [another demo](http://jsbin.com/wawozic/3/edit?html,js,output) *(a bit different implementation)*, and [one more demo](http://jsbin.com/wawozic/1/edit?html,js,output) *(using jQuery Appear instead of jQuery Waypoints)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
var circless = $(".circle");
var waypoint2 = new Waypoint({
    element: circless,
    handler: function(direction) {

        $(circless).circleProgress();
            this.destroy()
    },
    offset: '99%'
});
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation. Code only answers are usually harder to understand for future readers.